# IE Canvas dataURI Security Error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, internet-explorer-10

I am taking some SVG from the DOM, converting it to a dataURI, drawing it as an image to a canvas element and then reading a pixel of image data. This works nicely in chrome and FF, but IE 10 is giving me a security error.

[This is a link to a codepen](http://codepen.io/ZevanRosser/pen/pJZdav?editors=101)

This is the JavaScript:

```
var SVG_DATA_IMG = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64, ';
var utf8_to_b64 = function(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\&nbsp\;/g, ' ');
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
};
var svg = document.querySelector('#source-image');
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canv');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

img.src = SVG_DATA_IMG + utf8_to_b64(svg.innerHTML);

document.querySelector('#img').appendChild(img);

img.addEventListener('load', function() {
   canvas.width = img.offsetWidth;
   canvas.height = img.offsetHeight;
   console.log('loaded', ctx, canvas);
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   var centerPix = ctx.getImageData(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 1, 1).data;
   document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = [ 
     'center pixel color is:', centerPix[0], centerPix[1], centerPix[2], centerPix[3] ].join(', ')
});
```

and this is the html:

```
<div id="source-image">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="250" width="250" viewBox="-1 -1 250 250">
    <g>
      <path id="uniqueDomId-195" fill="#C0504D" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#8C3836" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M50,40 L60,87 12,92 42,129 0,146 37,174 12,201 55,203 55,241 84,203 97,221 109,193 129,211 136,179 166,193 164,159 211,174 184,139 203,126 191,104 241,74 181,72 201,37 161,64 164,2 129,47 109,22 97,72Z" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)" ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>


<canvas id="canv"></canvas>

<div id="img"></div>

<br />
<p id="output"></p>
```

The security error is not very informative:
[image]

As you can see I am trying to set the `crossOrigin` value for the image. I feel like there must be a simple solution for this.

**UPDATE**

Spent awhile getting a blob version of this same thing using `new Blob` and still get the same error.

Comment: Yep, Internet Explorer has harsher security restrictions and will not let you draw SVG onto the canvas as you are trying. I assume this is because MS is aware of a related security issue in IE. An interesting note about html5 canvas is that while canvas outputs a bitmap (raster) image, canvas uses vector-like commands to create drawings. Mike Swanson has a nice Adobe Illustrator plugin that exports SVG as native html5 canvas drawing commands: https://github.com/mikeswanson/Ai2Canvas. This converts your SVG drawing commands into CORS compliant html5 canvas drawing commands

Comment: thanks @markE - my technique actually works great and is extremely fast - however, I can't read pixels off the canvas after drawing the svg - just for drawing to the canvas alone this technique is nice. I've used canvg in the pase - Ai2Canvas looks great - thanks for the link - in the end I used canvg to solve the issue - but maybe Ai2Canvas would be a better fit... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```

Capital "A" because is not the same as "a": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: Setting the `cross-origin` flag will not help. Internet Explorer will still not allow SVG to be drawn to html5 Canvas without tainting the canvas.